# Error de inicio de sesión en POS Retail - AX 2012 R3 en Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, dynamics-ax, windows-server, windows-server-2012

Tengo instalado todo el marco de integración de un *Retail* en *AX 2012*. Todos los componentes y bases de datos están instaladas y conectadas correctamente.

Al arrancar el *POS*, salta el siguiente error:

> Error: 3/22/2017 a las 0:46:26 | *Microsoft Dynamics AX Retail*: *Retail POS* | El número del evento es 1 | Equipo: AX01.krsolution.es
>
> El teclado en pantalla no está disponible. La interfaz *COM* `IInputPanelConfiguracion` no está registrada. Lo más comúnmente se ve en las máquinas de *Windows Server* sin la *experiencia de escritorio* instalada. `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` (`0x80040154`) (`REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`).
>
> en `System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly,Boolean noCheck,Boolean canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)`.
>
> en `System.Runtime.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawl& stackMark)`.
>
> en `System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)`.
>
> en `System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)`.
>
> en `System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)`.
>
> en `LSRetailPosis.POS.frmMain.OnLoad(EventArgs e)`.

He comprobado todos los parámetros que se especifican en los manuales:

- Tiendas
- Workers vinculados a tiendas.
- Posiciones en tiendas
- Address book en tienda y worker.
- *Workers* con permisos.
- Dispositivos vinculados y activados para tienda.
- Todos los *jobs* de actualización ejecutados.
- etcétera...

Pero cuando me logueo con la identificación personal y la contraseña, el *POS* conecta con la base de datos (visor de eventos), pero no arranca ni carga nada... y me sigue mostrando el siguiente mensaje:

> [image: Atención] The *Operator ID* is not valid. `[OK]`

El *Operator ID* y la contraseña son correctos, pero no sé si es un problema de configuración, o si es otra cosa.

Comment: Gracias por traducir, tu pregunta está en proceso de reapertura. Un saludo